# facing exception while deploying liferay on weblogic

Tags: weblogic, liferay, yui-compressor

I've deployed liferay 5.2 sp2 on weblogic 10.3 and in deployment part the status of application is Active.
Now when i pass the URL in browser "nakulpatel:7001" it display "500--Internal Server Error".

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor
    at com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil._minifyJavaScript(MinifierUtil.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil.minifyJavaScript(MinifierUtil.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.strip(StripFilter.java:251)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:159)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)...
```

Please guide me how to fix this problem.
I've not used maven at all.Simply deployed .war file of liferay 5.2 and not able to start portal.

Comment: You are missing a dependency. Make sure you add `yuicompressor-[version].jar` to your classpath (preferrably to WEB-INF\lib in your .war file).

Comment: can i find the yuicompressor.jar from my .war file?

Comment: You tell me :) It should be there. It looks like liferay depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got it is because Liferay uses YUI compressor to do Javascript/CSS minification. Minification can be done in two ways -- runtime vs build time. It looks like liferay implements the former through servlet filter.

I checked my Liferay 6.0.x installation. There is a **liferay-yuicompressor.jar** under the `\liferay-portal-6.0.6\tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF`. Lfieray 5.2 should have a similar directory structure. Make sure this jar file is included in your `WEB-INF/lib` when deploying to WebLogic 10.3

Comment: Hi Surge,Thanks for reply.the liferay-yuicompressor.jar is in lib folder of domain.when i google it for more results show that i have to ant buuild-yui to create the liferay-yuicompressor.jar file.Please let me know did u follow this porcess?if yes , how?i ma facing java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive exception.

Comment: No, you do not need to use ant build-yui. As I said, you can do the minification in build time or runtime. Using ant is for build time. The exception you have indicates some jar file is corrupted. Can you open your war file with winzip? Also check the liferay-yuicompressor.jar inside to make sure it can be opened by winzip, since adding the jar file is the only thing you have changed in the war.