# how to ant build liferay-yuicompressor.jar?

Tags: jar, weblogic, liferay

I am using liferay 5.2 sp 2 on weblogic 10.

I need liferay-yuicompressor.jar file in the lib folder of domain.
I am tryign to create .jar file as per described on this link:
http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-3169

When i ant build-yui i am facing below exception.

get-swing-ex:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Liferay Material\GOSI\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\portal-impl\20130301133406114\rhino1_6R7\toolsrc\com\liferay\mozilla\javasc
ript\tools\debugger\downloaded
      [get] Getting: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/downloads/src.zip
      [get] To: D:\Liferay Material\GOSI\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\portal-impl\20130301133406114\rhino1_6R7\toolsrc\com\liferay\mozilla\javascript\tool
s\debugger\downloaded\swingExSrc.zip
      [get] http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/downloads/src.zip permanently moved to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html
    [unzip] Expanding: D:\Liferay Material\GOSI\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\portal-impl\20130301133406114\rhino1_6R7\toolsrc\com\liferay\mozilla\javascri
pt\tools\debugger\downloaded\swingExSrc.zip into D:\Liferay Material\GOSI\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\liferay-portal-src-5.2.2\portal-impl\20130301133406114\rhino1_6R7\toolsrc\co
m\liferay\mozilla\javascript\tools\debugger\downloaded

BUILD FAILED

As per my understanding it is trying to get the .zip file from   http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/downloads/src.zip
but it is no longer available and moved to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

I need your help in getting liferay-yuicompressor.jar file.
Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Nakul, I was responding your other post [facing exception while deploying liferay on weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130958/facing-exception-while-deploying-liferay-on-weblogic/15138957#15138957). Sorry I misunderstood your last comment on that post, as I used LifeRay 6.x, not 5.x.

How about we disable the minification for the runtime so that you do not need to use the liferay-yuicompressor.jar.

You can add the below to `portal-ext.properties`

```
javascript.fast.load=false 
theme.css.fast.load=false
```

If you still prefer to do minification for performance reason, you can do it during the build time as described here: http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/. Between runtime and build time minification, I always prefer build time.

Answer (score 0):

try to comment

```
<ant antfile="toolsrc/build.xml" target="compile"/>
```

into the root build.xml

more than that if you will have similiar problems with xbean.jar just set 
*without-xmlimpl: no*
into build.properties file